# How to remove the special characters in the columns and convert the columns into float

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the first and last characters in the column and convert the column into float. The column type is object.

my column data like this :

```
train['longtitude'].head()
0                 (29.760427,
1                 (29.760427,
2        (39.493240390000494,
3         (40.79373015200048,
4                  (37.77493,
5                 (39.952584,
```

I tried  this code ,but didn't work please help me how to do.

```
train['longtitude']= train['longtitude'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'(,', ' ', x)).replace('', np.float64(0)).astype('float64')
```

Here  the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-341a87b067e1> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 train['longtitude']= train['longtitude'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'(,', ' ', x)).replace('', np.float64(0)).astype('float64')

8 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    766             if not source.match(")"):
    767                 raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",
--> 768                                    source.tell() - start)
    769             if group is not None:
    770                 state.closegroup(group, p)

error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

I tried this code also , its thoughts  another error.

```
train['longtitude'].str.extract(r'(,').astype(float)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-192a820f7be0> in <module>()
----> 1 train['longtitude'].str.extract(r'(,').astype(float)

8 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    766             if not source.match(")"):
    767                 raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",
--> 768                                    source.tell() - start)
    769             if group is not None:
    770                 state.closegroup(group, p)

error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `train['longitude'].str[1:-1].astype(float)`, if you really want to remove the first and last characters.

To address your problem: the reason you get that error is that `(` is treated as the start of a capture group in a regex, so you should be able to fix it by escaping it like this: `\(`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try below as well using `replace` method:

`train['longitude'].str.replace("[\(,]", "", regex=True).astype(float)`